# Presenting New Views in SwiftUI Without a Button

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I want to present a new view using SwiftUI, without the user having to tap a button, since `NavigationButton` would work with that. Here is an example

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
        }.onAppear {
            if model.shouldPresent {
                // present a new view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onAppear` I want to include some code that will push a new view onto the navigation stack.

Comment: What's the question tho?

Comment: Can you simply drop the `.onAppear { }`? Or do you mean you want to segue _immediately_ to a different scene?

Comment: @NRitH To segue ipmegiately to another scene. The onAppear was just an example so that I could provide an example without having to include an entire view model.

Comment: As of Xcode 11 beta 4, SwiftUI's `NavigationView` does not provide any way to preload its stack with more than just a root view. It is indeed quite frustrating.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a way to present view as a Modal.

```
struct PresentOnloadView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Hey there")
            }
            .presentation(Modal(HelloView(), onDismiss: nil))
        }
}

struct HelloView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Whats up! ")
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you're looking to control whether to present or not using a variable, you can do something like this..

```
struct PresentOnloadControlledView : View {
  @State var sayHello = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
                Text("What's up!")
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                // Decide whether to show another view or not here
                self.sayHello = true
            })
            .presentation(sayHello ? Modal(HelloView()) : nil)
    }
}
```

> As of **Version 11.0 beta 4** ➝ **.presentation** and **Modal** has been deprecated.
>
> Not to worry! **.sheet** saves the day!

```
struct PresentOnloadControlledView : View {
  @State var sayHello = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("What's up!")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            // Decide whether to show another view or not here
            self.sayHello = true
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $sayHello) {
            HelloView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.presentation` works great, but is there a way to use it without wrapping the view in a `Model`?

Comment: .sheet is not getting called for me. hmm

Answer (score 3):

#### SwiftUI 2

Segue equivalents in SwiftUI 2 / iOS 14:

- Show (Push)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("First view")
                .background(NavigationLink("", destination: Text("Second view"), isActive: $showSecondView))
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Show Detail (Replace)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if showSecondView {
                Text("Second view")
            } else {
                Text("First view")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Present Modally

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("First view")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
            Text("Second view")
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Present as Full Screen

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("First view")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
            Text("Second view")
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                showSecondView = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I added `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)` so you can *see* the transition. You can remove it and the transition will start *immediately*.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your view:

```
@State var present = true

var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(), isActive: $present) {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

This code presents `DestinationView` as soon as the NavigationLink loads. The crucial part is the `isActive` parameter, which programmatically triggers the transition to the other View.

You could rewrite as follows

```
@State var present = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(), isActive: $present) {
        Button { 
            present = true
        } label: { Text("Present") }
    }
}
```

To manually create a navigation button.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply put the logic inside the `NavigationView`. Like this:

```
@State var x = true;

var body : some View {
    NavigationView {
        if x {
            Text("Hello")
            Button(action: {
                self.x = false;
            }, label: { Text("Click Me") })
        } else {
            Text("World")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn't actually push something onto the stack. It also seems a bit nuts that you would have to have essentially a giant if chain for your entire navigation stack.

Comment: In this case, `Text("World")` is that other view. But you could change that to be a custom view. It will embed it in the `body`, but you can change the animation type so that it _looks_ like anything is happening.

Comment: But it isn’t pushing into the navigation stack, which is far more important than the animation

Comment: `NavigationView`s do not push views on to the navigation stack. They act as a medium for `NavigationLink`s, which *do* present new views. Still, `NavigationLink`s are essentially buttons, so they require a tap gesture before anything will happen.