# How do I use SFSafariViewController with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, swiftui

I'm trying to present a `SFSafariViewController` from a `NavigationButton` but I'm not sure how to do that with SwiftUI.

In UIKit, I would just do:

```
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://google.com"), entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    vc.delegate = self

    present(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Supplemental to [Matteo Pacini post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518189/7341009), `.presentation(Modal())` [was removed by iOS 13's release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482854/7341009). This code should work (tested in Xcode 11.3, iOS 13.0 - 13.3):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct ContentView: View {
    // whether or not to show the Safari ViewController
    @State var showSafari = false
    // initial URL string
    @State var urlString = "https://duckduckgo.com"

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // update the URL if you'd like to
            self.urlString = "https://duckduckgo.com"
            // tell the app that we want to show the Safari VC
            self.showSafari = true
        }) {
            Text("Present Safari")
        }
        // summon the Safari sheet
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSafari) {
            SafariView(url:URL(string: self.urlString)!)
        }
    }
}

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {

    }

}
```

Comment: This works great! Would you know how to have the new Safari View open up so that it covers the entire screen? When this opens up the animation pushes the previous view down to create a gap between this new view and the top of the screen.

Alternatively, would you know how to prevent the previous View from being pushed down, so that the Safari View's navigation bar and the navigation bar of the previous View are seamless?

Comment: @gsamerica See [BetterSafariView](https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView). It presents a full-screen `SFSafariViewController` as its original style.

Comment: This works great, but I would like to add more to this answer. To anyone that wants to display a full screen, just replace .sheet with .fullScreenCover. 
 In addition, anyone who has trouble with the url not changing, it needs to be captured. In this case, it should be: 
 `.sheet(isPresented: $showSafari) { [urlString] in 
    SafariView(url:URL(string: urlString)!) 
 }` 
 or for full screen: 
 `.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSafari) { [urlString] in 
    SafariView(url:URL(string: urlString)!) 
 }`

Answer (score 13):

`SFSafariViewController` is a `UIKit` component, hence you need to make it `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

See [Integrating SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/231) WWDC 19 video for more details on how to bridge `UIKit` components to `SwiftUI`.

```swift
struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {

    }

}
```

A note of warning: `SFSafariViewController` is meant to be presented on top of another view controller, not pushed in a navigation stack.

It also has a navigation bar, meaning that if you push the view controller, you will see **two** navigation bars.

[image]

It seems to work - though it's glitchy - if presented modally.

```
struct ContentView : View {

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
        .presentation(Modal(SafariView(url:url)))
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I suggest porting `WKWebView` to `SwiftUI` via the `UIViewRepresentable` protocol, and use it in its stead.

Comment: For your modal example: `Use of unresolved identifier 'SafariView'`. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: @CME1Crewmember `SafariView` source code is at the very beginning of this answer

Comment: how to push SafariView into ContentView without seeing two nav bars, I just need the Safari nav bar only

Comment: @JAHelia What you want is possible using [BetterSafariView](https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView)

Answer (score 6):

Using **[BetterSafariView](https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView)**, you can present `SFSafariViewController` easily in SwiftUI. It works well as Apple intended, without losing its original push transition and swipe-to-dismiss gesture.

#### Usage

```swift
.safariView(isPresented: $presentingSafariView) {
    SafariView(url: URL("https://github.com/")!)
}
```

#### Example

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI
import BetterSafariView

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var presentingSafariView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present SafariView") {
            self.presentingSafariView = true
        }
        .safariView(isPresented: $presentingSafariView) {
            SafariView(
                url: URL(string: "https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView")!,
                configuration: SafariView.Configuration(
                    entersReaderIfAvailable: false,
                    barCollapsingEnabled: true
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AndrewPK, BetterSafariView itself is completely compatible with iOS 13 and Xcode 11. It seems like the error occurs because you're trying to pass wrong instance to the closure. Check out what I've just commented on the [GitHub issue that you opened](https://github.com/stleamist/BetterSafariView/issues/3).

Comment: yep - totally my bad. Going to delete my comment and I voted up your answer. Tl;dr - I was an idiot 

Comment: @Ixx Hmm... It should work even on a modal. Could you explain what is the problem, please?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the answer is to just not use SwiftUI!
This is so well supported in UIKit that I just make an easy bridge to UIKit so I can call the SafariController in a single line from SwiftUI like so:

```
HSHosting.openSafari(url:URL(string: "https://hobbyistsoftware.com")!)
```

I just replace UIHostingController at the top level of my app with HSHostingController

(note - this class also allows you to control the presentation style of modals)

```
//HSHostingController.swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

class HSHosting {
    static var controller:UIViewController?
    static var nextModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationStyle?

    static func openSafari(url:URL,tint:UIColor? = nil) {
        guard let controller = controller else {
            preconditionFailure("No controller present. Did you remember to use HSHostingController instead of UIHostingController in your SceneDelegate?")
        }

        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)  

        vc.preferredBarTintColor = tint
        //vc.delegate = self

        controller.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class HSHostingController<Content> : UIHostingController<Content> where Content : View {

    override init(rootView: Content) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView)

        HSHosting.controller = self
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        if let nextStyle = HSHosting.nextModalPresentationStyle {
            viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = nextStyle
            HSHosting.nextModalPresentationStyle = nil
        }

        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

use HSHostingController instead of UIHostingController in your scene delegate
like so:

```
    // Use a HSHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        //This is the only change from the standard boilerplate
        window.rootViewController = HSHostingController(rootView: contentView)

        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

then when you want to open SFSafariViewController, just call:

```
HSHosting.openSafari(url:URL(string: "https://hobbyistsoftware.com")!)
```

for example

```
Button(action: {
    HSHosting.openSafari(url:URL(string: "https://hobbyistsoftware.com")!)
}) {
    Text("Open Web")
}
```

update: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ConfusedVorlon/81dccc9ff2309f8c300e9ed8c42d0906) for extended solution with additional capabilities

Comment: If I would ask how to use X in Y, would you advise not to use Y?

Comment: This is the only answer I've seen that properly presents the SFSafariViewController in the standard, full-screen, non-modal presentation. As @ConfusedVorlon said, it can be used in SwiftUI. Thanks for this!

Comment: This works with iOS 13 && Xcode 11, which means this solution works for folks shipping to the app store before the Xcode 12 GM is available.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative version of [bheinz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59448652/2210960)'s answer using Identifiable protocol.

Wrap `SFSafariViewController` for SwiftUI

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {

    }

}
```

Use it like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Conformance to Identifiable is needed for sheet presentation
extension URL: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        self.absoluteString
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // When set it will present Safari
    @State var presentURL: URL?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present Safari") {
            presentURL = URL(string: "https://duckduckgo.com")!
        }
        // summon the Safari sheet
        .sheet(item: $presentUrl) { url in
            SafariView(url: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer for this question on whole stack overflow...!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer if using a WKWebView, but again it still doesn't look right.

```
struct SafariView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            view.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in SwiftUI, even preserving the default appearance, but you need to expose a UIViewController to work with. Start with defining a SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable that is passed a boolean binding and an activation handler:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ViewControllerBridge: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    let action: (UIViewController, Bool) -> Void

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        action(uiViewController, isActive)
    }
}
```

Then, give the widget you plan to show the SafariVC from a state property determining if it should be shown, then add this bridge to show the VC when the state changes.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var isSafariShown = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Safari") {
            self.isSafariShown = true
        }
        .background(
            ViewControllerBridge(isActive: $isSafariShown) { vc, active in
                if active {
                    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
                    vc.present(safariVC, animated: true) {
                        // Set the variable to false when the user dismisses the safari VC
                        self.isSafariShown = false
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        )
    }
}
```

Note that I give the ViewControllerBridge a fixed frame with a zero width and height, that means you can put this anywhere in your view hierarchy and it won't cause any significant change to your UI.

--Jakub

Comment: This presented it exactly the way I wanted, but the SFSafariViewController wouldn't load the website, and the Console said:  `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UIViewController: 0x7faa34967ef0>.`

Comment: Well, from what you've written it seems like you added the bridge to a view that isn't shown on-screen when you try to present the website. Try making sure the bridge is attached to a view that's shown on-screen, otherwise try to post the code you're using.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with this code. Same warning message and the page stays blank.

Answer (score 1):

Since most (if not all) answers here are focused on modal presentation of `SFSafariViewController` in SwiftUI, here's an example for pushing it to the `NavigationView` stack (along with [making "pop" to work when system "Done" button is tapped in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659486?answerId=744272022#744272022)):

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    let urls: [URL]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(urls) { url in
                    NavigationLink(destination: {
                        SafariView(url: url)
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                    }, label: {
                        Text(url.absoluteString)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        vc.preferredControlTintColor = .tintColor
        vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ vc: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {}

    class Coordinator: NSObject, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
        var dismissAction: DismissAction?

        func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
            dismissAction?()
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        let coordinator = Coordinator()
        coordinator.dismissAction = dismiss
        return coordinator
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like other people have already said, you can use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. I've just cut the code a little bit:

```
struct SafariVCRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context _: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        .init(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_: SFSafariViewController, context _: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: These are the extension stubs Xcode 15 suggests so I feel like this is the most current answer.

Comment: I have not tried Xcode 15 yet, because it is in beta now. What stubs are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

None of above is working for me because I was trying to present the SFSafariViewController in a list of buttons. I ended up using a binding.

Make the binding in your view controller:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var guideHostingViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: UserGuideView(presentUrl: presentBinding))

    @objc private func showWebsite() {
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: guideHostingViewController)
        present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    private var presentBinding: Binding<URL> {
        return Binding<URL>(
            get: {
                return URL(string: "https://www.percento.app")!
            },
            set: {
                self.guideHostingViewController.present(SFSafariViewController(url: $0), animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI list:

```
struct UserGuideView: View {
    private let guidePages: [SitePage] = [.multiCurrency, .stockSync, .dataSafety, .privacy]
    @Binding var presentUrl: URL

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(guidePages) { page in
                Button(action: {
                    presentUrl = page.localiedContentUrl
                }) {
                    Text(page.description)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                        .modifier(UserGuideRowModifier(icon: .init(systemName: page.systemIconName ?? "")))
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationBarTitle(NSLocalizedString("User Guide", comment: "User Guide navigation bar"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Zika M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4849905), to change url we need to capture it. Made the required changes as follow:

```
import SafariServices

struct ContentView: View {
    // whether or not to show the Safari ViewController
    @State var showSafari = false
    // initial URL string
    @State var urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // update the URL if you'd like to
            self.urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"
            // tell the app that we want to show the Safari VC
            self.showSafari = true
        }) {
            Text("Present Safari")
        }
        // summon the Safari sheet
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSafari) { [urlString] in
            SafariView(url:URL(string: urlString)!)
        }

        //For Fullscreen
        //.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSafari) { [urlString] in
        //    SafariView(url:URL(string: urlString)!)
        //}
    }
}

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

On an **XCode 14.3.1**, **Swift 5.8** and **macOS 13.2**, it was as easy as this for me:

```
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") else {
            return
        }
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(vc, animated: true)
```

Put this code inside the handler that initiates a browser open event like a link/button click.
**Don't forget to import the package**.

`import SafariServices`

I forgot this and I was getting the following error:
`cannot find 'sfsafariviewcontroller' in scope`
before chatGPT was kind enough to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Question is about SwiftUI, "present" is an UIKit function

Comment: "present" is a UIKit function not an UIKit - Reason: UIKit starts with a non-vowel sound.