# SwiftUI: SafariView in Master-Detail View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to display SafariView in the Detail view in a Master-Detail view set up on iPad, but my implementation resulted in a "pushed down" SafariView.

See image:
[image]

I have tried various solutions in this SO post but none seem to work in my use case. Most solution pushes a SafariView over the entire Master-Detail View (for this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61119029/6792327), see gif) or presents a sheet ([BetterSafariView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438651/6792327)).

[image]

```
struct ItemsListView: View {   
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    SafariDetailView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SafariDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".uppercased())
                Text("23 Dec 2021")
            }

            Spacer()

            NavigationLink(
                destination: NormalSafariView(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!),
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
                .frame(width: 0)
        }
    }
}

struct NormalSafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NormalSafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<NormalSafariView>) {
        
    }
    
}
```

My requirement requires that the implementation shows the SafariView on the detail view when in a Master-Detail setup on iPad, and a "push"-like transition on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "pushed down" behaviour of the `NormalSafariView` is because it is in a `NavigationView`, so by default, it is living a place for you ( the `navigationBar`), where you can provide a `navigationTitle`, a toolbar, etc.

To fix that, a simple solution is to hide the `navigationBarHidden` for the `NormalSafariView` view.

Change your `NavigationLink` from:

```
 NavigationLink(
                destination: NormalSafariView(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!),
                label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
                .frame(width: 0)
```

to:

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: NormalSafariView(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
        .navigationBarHidden(true) // This will completely hide the navigation bar
    ,
    label: {
        EmptyView()
    })
    .frame(width: 0)
```

In addition, you can use:

```
.navigationTitle("Safari View") // Use this if you want a navigation bar with a big title
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // Combine this with `navigationTitle if you want a navigation bar with small title.
```